# Where does Fedora Media Writer save any ISOs it downloads?

Tags: linux, fedora

Where does Fedora Media Writer save any ISO files it downloads?

Comment: On mine it saves them to /home/user/Downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora Media Writer is a QT app, and it uses that library to get a standard path for the operating system in use. From the [qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html), that looks to be:

```
 Linux:         ~/Downloads
 Mac OS X:      ~/Downloads
 Windows:       "C:/Users/<USER>/Documents"
```

and it'd do similar things on Android and iOS, if we had a Fedora Media Writer version for those, which we don't currently.

Comment: For windows (7 at least) it is in Downloads folder too, like other OS, not in Documents.